# Error while XOR ing C++

Tags: c++, xor

I have problem, when i compile this code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

const unsigned long box[256]=   {   0xD1310BA6, 0x98DFB5AC, 0x2FFD72DB, 0xD01ADFB7,
    0xB8E1AFED, 0x6A267E96, 0xBA7C9045, 0xF12C7F99,
    0x24A19947, 0xB3916CF7, 0x0801F2E2, 0x858EFC16,
    0x636920D8, 0x71574E69, 0xA458FEA3, 0xF4933D7E,
    0x0D95748F, 0x728EB658, 0x718BCD58, 0x82154AEE,
    0x7B54A41D, 0xC25A59B5, 0x9C30D539, 0x2AF26013,
    0xC5D1B023, 0x286085F0, 0xCA417918, 0xB8DB38EF,
    0x8E79DCB0, 0x603A180E, 0x6C9E0E8B, 0xB01E8A3E,
    0xD71577C1, 0xBD314B27, 0x78AF2FDA, 0x55605C60,
    0xE65525F3, 0xAA55AB94, 0x57489862, 0x63E81440,
    0x55CA396A, 0x2AAB10B6, 0xB4CC5C34, 0x1141E8CE,
    0xA15486AF, 0x7C72E993, 0xB3EE1411, 0x636FBC2A,
    0x2BA9C55D, 0x741831F6, 0xCE5C3E16, 0x9B87931E,
    0xAFD6BA33, 0x6C24CF5C, 0x7A325381, 0x28958677,
    0x3B8F4898, 0x6B4BB9AF, 0xC4BFE81B, 0x66282193,
    0x61D809CC, 0xFB21A991, 0x487CAC60, 0x5DEC8032,
    0xEF845D5D, 0xE98575B1, 0xDC262302, 0xEB651B88,
    0x23893E81, 0xD396ACC5, 0x0F6D6FF3, 0x83F44239,
    0x2E0B4482, 0xA4842004, 0x69C8F04A, 0x9E1F9B5E,
    0x21C66842, 0xF6E96C9A, 0x670C9C61, 0xABD388F0,
    0x6A51A0D2, 0xD8542F68, 0x960FA728, 0xAB5133A3,
    0x6EEF0B6C, 0x137A3BE4, 0xBA3BF050, 0x7EFB2A98,
    0xA1F1651D, 0x39AF0176, 0x66CA593E, 0x82430E88,
    0x8CEE8619, 0x456F9FB4, 0x7D84A5C3, 0x3B8B5EBE,
    0xE06F75D8, 0x85C12073, 0x401A449F, 0x56C16AA6,
    0x4ED3AA62, 0x363F7706, 0x1BFEDF72, 0x429B023D,
    0x37D0D724, 0xD00A1248, 0xDB0FEAD3, 0x49F1C09B,
    0x075372C9, 0x80991B7B, 0x25D479D8, 0xF6E8DEF7,
    0xE3FE501A, 0xB6794C3B, 0x976CE0BD, 0x04C006BA,
    0xC1A94FB6, 0x409F60C4, 0x5E5C9EC2, 0x196A2463,
    0x68FB6FAF, 0x3E6C53B5, 0x1339B2EB, 0x3B52EC6F,
    0x6DFC511F, 0x9B30952C, 0xCC814544, 0xAF5EBD09,
    0xBEE3D004, 0xDE334AFD, 0x660F2807, 0x192E4BB3,
    0xC0CBA857, 0x45C8740F, 0xD20B5F39, 0xB9D3FBDB,
    0x5579C0BD, 0x1A60320A, 0xD6A100C6, 0x402C7279,
    0x679F25FE, 0xFB1FA3CC, 0x8EA5E9F8, 0xDB3222F8,
    0x3C7516DF, 0xFD616B15, 0x2F501EC8, 0xAD0552AB,
    0x323DB5FA, 0xFD238760, 0x53317B48, 0x3E00DF82,
    0x9E5C57BB, 0xCA6F8CA0, 0x1A87562E, 0xDF1769DB,
    0xD542A8F6, 0x287EFFC3, 0xAC6732C6, 0x8C4F5573,
    0x695B27B0, 0xBBCA58C8, 0xE1FFA35D, 0xB8F011A0,
    0x10FA3D98, 0xFD2183B8, 0x4AFCB56C, 0x2DD1D35B,
    0x9A53E479, 0xB6F84565, 0xD28E49BC, 0x4BFB9790,
    0xE1DDF2DA, 0xA4CB7E33, 0x62FB1341, 0xCEE4C6E8,
    0xEF20CADA, 0x36774C01, 0xD07E9EFE, 0x2BF11FB4,
    0x95DBDA4D, 0xAE909198, 0xEAAD8E71, 0x6B93D5A0,
    0xD08ED1D0, 0xAFC725E0, 0x8E3C5B2F, 0x8E7594B7,
    0x8FF6E2FB, 0xF2122B64, 0x8888B812, 0x900DF01C,
    0x4FAD5EA0, 0x688FC31C, 0xD1CFF191, 0xB3A8C1AD,
    0x2F2F2218, 0xBE0E1777, 0xEA752DFE, 0x8B021FA1,
    0xE5A0CC0F, 0xB56F74E8, 0x18ACF3D6, 0xCE89E299,
    0xB4A84FE0, 0xFD13E0B7, 0x7CC43B81, 0xD2ADA8D9,
    0x165FA266, 0x80957705, 0x93CC7314, 0x211A1477,
    0xE6AD2065, 0x77B5FA86, 0xC75442F5, 0xFB9D35CF,
    0xEBCDAF0C, 0x7B3E89A0, 0xD6411BD3, 0xAE1E7E49,
    0x00250E2D, 0x2071B35E, 0x226800BB, 0x57B8E0AF,
    0x2464369B, 0xF009B91E, 0x5563911D, 0x59DFA6AA,
    0x78C14389, 0xD95A537F, 0x207D5BA2, 0x02E5B9C5,
    0x83260376, 0x6295CFA9, 0x11C81968, 0x4E734A41,
    0xB3472DCA, 0x7B14A94A, 0x1B510052, 0x9A532915,
    0xD60F573F, 0xBC9BC6E4, 0x2B60A476, 0x81E67400,
    0x08BA6FB5, 0x571BE91F, 0xF296EC6B, 0x2A0DD915,
    0xB6636521, 0xE7B9F9B6, 0xFF34052E, 0xC5855664,
    0x53B02D5D, 0xA99F8FA1, 0x08BA4799, 0x6E85076A   };
    for (int x = 0;x<=255;x++){
        cout<< sbox[x]^ sbox[x]<<endl;



    }
    return 0;

}
```

I get an error which says:

```
[Error] invalid operands of types ‘const long unsigned int’ and
‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator<<’".
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You create `box`, but use `sbox`, probably typo?

Comment: To summarize answers: when in doubt, use parentheses.

Comment: To add one more note to the answers: what are you hoping to achieve by printing 256 zeros?

Comment: actualy im trying something other this was just an syntax check.

Comment: Accept hyde's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Order of operations: `<<` is higher than `^`.

Put parentheses around `sbox[x]^ sbox[x]`:

```
 cout << (sbox[x]^sbox[x]) << endl;
```